# Flutter - Push Notifications

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase notifications in my app and they are working fine when the app is in foreground or when user taps on a notification and launches the app. Is there any way to read notification when app comes to foreground (by launching it directly) without user tapping on the notification?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

When you receive notification, save the content of the title and then check for saved notification contents when app starts

```
void saveNotification(){
    // save notification content here
}
```

When user launches app

```
void checkPendingNotification(){
    // show notification here if any
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, the problem is when app is in background onResume doesn't get called till you tap on notification and launch the application.